# EEA Family Permit Supporting Documents

Tags: immigration

I have recently applied for an EEA Family Permit for my mom. I'm a Dutch National and will be migrating to the UK tin the next few weeks. The application process was rather quite simple and easy, but I'm quite confused about one of the documents that they're asking for.

So my mom needs to bring a "The Passport or travel document for the sponsor (me) from British Citizen" I have no idea what they could be asking for since I'm clearly requesting an EEA Family Permit and wouldn't be able to do so if I was a British National. I also clearly stated on the application form that I was a Dutch National.

Any clues to which document they're asking for?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your reply.

It absolutely didn't even match grammatically. They had already asked for a copy of my bio page from my passport, so I'm still unsure why they would ask again for it. They could have simply just asked for the passport one time only. Quite confusing! I just hope everything goes smoothly. But I'll def return to let you know how it went.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the request mentions "British citizen" in error.  Even still, it is confusing, because the phrase "sponsor from British citizen" does not make sense.  If it was written by a Dutch-speaking employee, we could posit that "from" is a mistranslation of "van," and should be "of" instead.  But while that makes more sense grammatically, it makes less sense practically, for the idea of a sponsor *of* a British citizen is nonsensical in the context of UK immigration.

Your mother should bring your passport or national ID card.