# European Family Permit Documents

Tags: resident-permit, family

I'm applying for an EEA Family Permit. My husband is an Austrian national and will be migrating to the UK in the next few weeks. The application process was rather quite simple and easy, but I'm quite confused about one of the documents that they're asking for.

I needs to bring a "The Passport or travel document for the sponsor (my husband) from British Citizen" I have no idea what they could be asking for since I'm clearly requesting an EEA Family Permit and wouldn't be able to do so if I was a British National. I also clearly stated on the application form that I was a Dutch National.

Any clues to which document they're asking for? Is this a mistake?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/17348/eea-family-permit-supporting-documents

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EEA Family Permit Supporting Documents](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/17348/eea-family-permit-supporting-documents)

Comment: @phoog The two links resolve to the same SE:Expatriates page.

Comment: @David yes, but when the first link was posted, it was not actually possible to vote to close as a duplicate because neither of the existing answers on the other question had been upvoted or accepted.  I upvoted one answer so I could vote to close this question as a duplicate of that one, whereupon the system added the second comment above.

Comment: Hi, the problem is that the question that the person asks isn't really resolved. Should I proceed with the application?

Comment: The grammar is awful and the conclusion irrational, as pointed out in the linked question. On the other hand, there are only two people involved here, you and your husband. To cover all the possibilities, bring both of your passports and travel documents.